# Error creating bean Cassandra in Spring MVC Project

Tags: spring-mvc, cassandra

I tried to make the project cassandra in spring MVC, trying to display the data in the controller, the controller:

```
package com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.entity.Employee;
import com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.service.EmployeeService;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
   @Autowired
   EmployeeService employeeService;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {

    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    employees = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        System.out.println("ID: " + employee.getId());
        System.out.println("NAME: " + employee.getName());
        System.out.println("SALARY: " + employee.getSalary());
    }

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,   DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

    return "home";
   }
}
```

EmployeeDAOImpl:

```
package com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.dao;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.entity.Employee;
import com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.util.MyCassandraTemplate;


@Repository
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

    @Autowired
    private MyCassandraTemplate myCassandraTemplate;

    @Override
    public Employee createEmployee(Employee employee) {     
        return myCassandraTemplate.create(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployee(int id) {       
        return myCassandraTemplate.findById(id, Employee.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Employee updateEmployee(Employee employee) {     
        return myCassandraTemplate.update(employee, Employee.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployee(int id) {        
        myCassandraTemplate.deleteById(id, Employee.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {       
        return myCassandraTemplate.findAll(Employee.class);
    }
}
```

EmployeeServiceImpl:

```
package com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.entity.Employee;

@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {
    @Autowired  
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    public EmployeeServiceImpl() {
        super();    
    }

    @Override   
    public Employee createEmployee(Employee employee) {     
        return employeeDAO.createEmployee(employee);
    }

    @Override   
    public Employee getEmployee(int id) {       
        return employeeDAO.getEmployee(id);
    }

    @Override   
    public Employee updateEmployee(Employee employee) {     
        return employeeDAO.updateEmployee(employee);
    }

    @Override   
    public void deleteEmployee(int id) {        
        employeeDAO.deleteEmployee(id);
    }

    @Override   
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {       
        return employeeDAO.getAllEmployees();
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
package com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.entity;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;

@Table("employee")
public class Employee {

@PrimaryKey("id")
private long id;    

@Column("name")
private String name;    

/*@Column
private int age;    */

@Column(value ="salary")
private float salary;

/**
 * Default Constructor
 */
public Employee() {
    super();        
}

/**
 * Parameterized Constructor
 * @param id
 * @param name
 * @param age
 * @param salary
 */
public Employee(long id, String name, float salary) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    //this.age = age;
    this.salary = salary;
}

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return the age
 */
/*public int getAge() {
    return age;
}*/

/**
 * @param age the age to set
 */
/*public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}*/

/**
 * @return the salary
 */
public float getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

/**
 * @param salary the salary to set
 */
public void setSalary(float salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age="
            + ", salary=" + salary + "]";
}
```

}

CassandraUtil:

```
package com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.util;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraClusterFactoryBean;
import    org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SchemaAction;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CassandraConverter;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:cassandra.properties" })
public class CassandraUtil {

    private static final String KEYSPACE = "cassandra.keyspace";
    private static final String CONTACTPOINTS = "cassandra.contactpoints";
    private static final String PORT = "cassandra.port";

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    public CassandraUtil() {
        System.out.println("CassandraUtil()");
    }

    private String getKeyspaceName() {
        return environment.getProperty(KEYSPACE);       
    }

    private String getContactPoints() {
        return environment.getProperty(CONTACTPOINTS);        
    }

    private int getPortNumber() {
        return Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty(PORT));        
    }

    @Bean
public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
    cluster.setContactPoints(getContactPoints());
    cluster.setPort(getPortNumber());
    return cluster;
}

@Bean
public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
    return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
}

@Bean
public CassandraConverter converter() {
    return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
}

@Bean
public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {
    CassandraSessionFactoryBean cassandraSessionFactoryBean = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
    cassandraSessionFactoryBean.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
    cassandraSessionFactoryBean.setKeyspaceName(getKeyspaceName());
    cassandraSessionFactoryBean.setConverter(converter());
    cassandraSessionFactoryBean.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);
    return cassandraSessionFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
}
}
```

MyCassandraTemplate:

```
package com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.util;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class MyCassandraTemplate {

@Autowired
private CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate;


public MyCassandraTemplate() {
    System.out.println("MyCassandraTemplate()");
}


public <T> T create(T entity) {
    return cassandraTemplate.insert(entity);
}


public <T> void createList(List<T> entities) {
    cassandraTemplate.insert(entities);     
}


public <T> T update(T entity) {     
    return (T) cassandraTemplate.update(entity);
}


public <T> void updateList(List<T> entities) {      
    cassandraTemplate.update(entities);
}


public <T> T update(T entity, Class<T> claz) {      
    return (T) cassandraTemplate.update(entity);
}


public <T> T findById(Object id, Class<T> claz) {
    return cassandraTemplate.selectOneById(claz, id);
}


public <T> void deleteById(Object id, Class<T> claz) {
    cassandraTemplate.deleteById(claz, id);
}


public void delete(Object entity) {
    cassandraTemplate.delete(entity);
}


public <T> void delete(List<T> entities) {
    cassandraTemplate.delete(entities);
}


public <T> void deleteAll(Class<T> claz) {
    cassandraTemplate.deleteAll(claz);
}


public <T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> claz) {
    return (List<T>) cassandraTemplate.selectAll(claz);
}


public <T> List<T> findAll(List<Object> ids, Class<T> claz) {
    return cassandraTemplate.selectBySimpleIds(claz, ids);
}


public <T> void truncate(Class<T> claz) {
    cassandraTemplate.truncate(claz.getName());
}


public <T> long getCount(Class<T> claz) {
    return cassandraTemplate.count(claz);
}   


public <T> boolean exists(Object id, Class<T> claz) {
    return cassandraTemplate.exists(claz, id);
}
}
```

Application context in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc          
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc" />
```

Here is my error while the program was running:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.util.MyCassandraTemplate com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl.myCassandraTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myCassandraTemplate': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.util.MyCassandraTemplate.cassandraTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/pji/cassandraInSpringMvc/util/CassandraUtil.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.util.CassandraUtil.cassandraTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/pji/cassandraInSpringMvc/util/CassandraUtil.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/concurrent/EventExecutor
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.util.MyCassandraTemplate com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl.myCassandraTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myCassandraTemplate': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.util.MyCassandraTemplate.cassandraTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/pji/cassandraInSpringMvc/util/CassandraUtil.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations com.pji.cassandraInSpringMvc.util.CassandraUtil.cassandraTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/pji/cassandraInSpringMvc/util/CassandraUtil.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/concurrent/EventExecutor
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anybody help me please

Answer (score 0):

The code that you above looks good. The problems is with your pom.xml. Please try to remove the version in the spring-data-cassandra if you have a version mentioned there.
        
            org.springframework.data
            spring-data-cassandra